# Did MasterCard change the shape of their cards? Or is the shape chosen by the bank?

Tags: credit-card, debit-card, mastercard, accessibility

I read on [npr.org](https://www.npr.org/2021/11/02/1051365892/mastercard-unveils-new-card-feature-to-help-blind-customers#:%7E:text=Credit%20cards%20have%20a%20round,triangular%20notch%2C%20the%20company%20said.) that:

> Credit cards have a round notch; debit cards have a broad, square notch; and prepaid cards have a triangular notch, the company said.

However, my Wise debit card (MasterCard) has a round notch. Did MasterCard change the shape of their cards? Or is the shape chosen by the bank?

---

The [3 shape types:](https://www.npr.org/2021/11/02/1051365892/mastercard-unveils-new-card-feature-to-help-blind-customers#:%7E:text=Credit%20cards%20have%20a%20round,triangular%20notch%2C%20the%20company%20said.)

[image]

Wise debit card (2023-01):

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Yes. See [here](https://www.mastercard.com/news/press/2021/october/mastercard-introduces-accessible-card-for-blind-and-partially-sighted-people/):

> Note: Since launch of the Touch Card, the shape of the notches were changed to reflect further refinement of the card.

Comment: My UK bank issued Mastercard debit card has the notch like Wise card above, but looking at the front, it is at the bottom right.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Bottom right / top left isn't as important as "opposite the chip" so the user knows which end to insert into the chip reader.